# Drawing a line section of length $\sqrt[3]2$

Tags: geometry

As a well-known fact, we know how to draw a line segment of length $\sqrt[2]2$ with  a compass. Even a line segment of length $\pi$ can be obtained (at least theoretically) by opening and flattening a circle of unit diameter. My question is

> How can one draw a line segment of length $\sqrt[3]2$ with just a simple compass, ruler and straight edge on a $2$D plane without touching the third dimension?

Comment: You can't since $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not a constructible number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number for details.

Comment: Thank you. That was useful.

Comment: There is a simple neusis construction for $\sqrt[3]2$, which you can find in the wiki article on [doubling the cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube) or elsewhere.  In particular, that construction shows that it is perfectly possible if you allow a marked ruler (forbidden under the strict rules of construction of course).

Comment: Nice one as well. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what a "ruler" is in the question.  Sometimes ths term is used for a marked device versus an unmarked "straightedge".

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that you can't actually draw a line segment of length $\pi$. That is, $\pi$ is not a constructible number. What operation that you can perform with a compass and straight edge "opens and flattens" a circle of unit diameter? However, as @OscarLanzi points out, having access to a ruler changes the game a bit. I don't know anything about the set of numbers that can be constructed with a ruler.

Comment: @Charles see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction).  A marked ruler alone solves equations up to degree 4 (so that is all you actually need to trisect an angle).  With compasses also some quintic and sextic equations are added but we do not know exactly which such equations.